Dark fantasy novel featuring Es, a faerie seeking to be queen, and a fae expert who can make a special fae brew, allowing levitation
I read this book years ago (it's not something recently written), but the book and I have parted ways at some point, and I cannot remember the title, or author! Google has no answers, nor Goodreads. But I know the book exists...
It's about a faerie named Es (but humans called her Rose), who escaped captivity with three other fae, rather violently. One of the fae was mortally wounded during the escape, and passed away, after which the remaining three (Es included) all parted ways. Each had a single goal in mind... become the next Faerie queen. To do so, Es must find a safe, sheltered place for her court that she plans to bring together, she must collect gold, and to bear a son. Male fae are so rare in their world, that any male child is instant royalty... and his mother elevated to royal status.
There are human characters as well, but I've long since forgotten their names. I only remember the man's boss' name was Chadwick (and he didn't like being called Chad, for short) ... it struck me as odd at the time, probably the reason that tidbit of information stuck. There's a man the main human characters go to see, who has become something of an expert on the fae, even having learned how to make the special fae brew which allows humans to levitate.
The novel itself is not some cozy, lighthearted fairy tale... it's a dark, bloody story. Not a children's book at all.

How certain are you about those names (Es, Chadwick, Rose)? Where are you likely to have read this, was it a paper book or something you found online?

I'm 100% certain about those names. Any details I'm not absolutely certain about, I don't mention. It was a paperback novel. And I read it quite a few years ago (I don't remember the exact time frame, but I know I've been looking for it again for more than a decade).

Why do they call her Rose if her name is Es?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?
